Replenishment of electrons in an AC wiring system, after disconnecting battery charger?
I was wondering when you have a system which begins of course with the source of AC Electrical current, are on an isolated segment of that system, say connecting a segment of the power grid to a house, past the end of a transformer,  and you plug in a battery charger, charger your battery, and then unplug it, where are the electrons mostly coming from that replenish those lost from the ac wiring ?

The AC wiring never gains or loses electrons. That part is always kept neutral. The electrons slosh around.
